# Trying to get the data(of mongodb) to the client side for the specific field (data.site.alerts.alert)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rxjs, jsx

*****My code *****

```
import logo from './logo.svg'; 
import './App.css'; 
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import axios from 'axios';
 
export default class App extends Component {

  state = {
    arraydata: []   
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getmongodbdata();   }

  getmongodbdata = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/fetch').then(res => {
      console.log(res.data,)
      console.log('Data is recieved')
      this.setState({arraydata: res.data})
    })
    .catch(() => {
      alert('Sorry, could not able to fetch the data');
    })   }
  

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="Main">
         <header className="App-header">
           <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
           <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to Future</h1>
         </header> 

         <h1> hello world</h1>

         <ul key={'qw'}>
           {this.state.arraydata.map((data, index) => {
             return <li key={`ui-${index}`}>
               {data._id}
           </li>
         })}
         </ul>

      </div>
    )   } }
```

***Screenshot for better understanding**
[image]

***At the moment***
I'm getting the id from the data by doing:

```
<ul key={'qw'}>
  {this.state.arraydata.map((data, index) => {
         return <li key={`ui-${index}`}>
           {data._id}
         </li>
       })}
     </ul>
```

***What i want to get ***
is to get inside the `data.site.alerts.alert` (show the alert column)

for that I'm trying to do

```
     <ul key={'qw'}>
       {this.state.arraydata.map((data, index) => {
         return <li key={`ui-${index}`}>
           {data._id}
           <ul key={`alert-ui-${index}`}>
              {data.site.alerts.map((alertData, alertIndex)=>{
                return <li key={`alert-li-${alertIndex}`}>{alertData.alert}</li> 
              });
           </ul>
         </li>
       })}
     </ul>
```

but getting error map cannot use property that is not undefined.

Comment: My be the initial state fails try this `{this.state.arraydata && this.state.arraydata.map(...`

Answer (score 0):

I often find that react throws errors even when the data mapped over is not undefined, so  a lot of times you just have to use some inline conditional like [@prasanth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6235047/prasanth) said:

```
<ul key={'qw'}>
  {this.state.arraydata?.map((data, index) => {
    return <li key={`ui-${index}`}>
      {data._id}
      <ul key={`alert-ui-${index}`}>
         {data.site.alerts.map((alertData, alertIndex)=>{
           return <li key={`alert-li-${alertIndex}`}>{alertData.alert}</li> 
         });
      </ul>
    </li>
  })}
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul key={'qw'}>
  {this.state.arraydata ? this.state.arraydata.map((data, index) => {
    return <li key={`ui-${index}`}>
      {data._id}
      <ul key={`alert-ui-${index}`}>
         {data.site.alerts.map((alertData, alertIndex)=>{
           return <li key={`alert-li-${alertIndex}`}>{alertData.alert}</li> 
         }) : /* say something */;
      </ul>
    </li>
  })}
</ul>
```

or something along those lines.

Comment: thanks for your help guys, I found how to do it, I used the {data.site[index].alerts.map(.......} to get the value inside the alert as the alert is also an array.